# Can't chose Rest Of World option in google play developer console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

For alpha version of the game I'm trying to pick all countries (including "Rest Of World").

But when I press "Save" id doesn't save it. So, "Rest Of World" is not available for alpha build or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Is it a paid or free app?

Comment: @Elletlar free.

Comment: I can confirm that it is allowed for beta because I selected "Rest of the World" on one of my apps that is in beta. It now reports "Beta Countries 232 + Rest of the World". However, my app is both in production and beta so that may be the difference.

Comment: @Elletlar our game is not in prod right now, only alpha/beta versions are live.

Comment: If you want I could create a new dummy app and place it into alpha as a test, but it might be worth reporting it to Google because it doesn't seem right.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, I'd report to the Play Console support team. You can do this through the help menu (behind the "?" question mark icon)

Comment: @NickFortescue they said, that you can't pick this option for paid apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the answer from Google Support. Referring to [this article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286?hl=en), you can't chose "Rest Of World" option for paid apps (if you need to buy it before play, or if you have in-app products).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that's entirely the case. I can confirm that I'm unable to select 'rest of the world' for paid apps which makes sense. For my free apps with in app purchases handled via GooglePlay, I'm able to select 'Rest of the World' on all of them, but when ticking that option it gives a warning that users will not be able to make purchases. I suspect the option will start working for you at some point probably after the app is fully released.

Comment: @Elletlar yes, I've asked about this case and they said that you can't do it. Meh, google support as always...

Comment: They are clearly wrong because we have a counter example, but I'd try it again after it is fully released. Cheers.

Comment: @Elletlar you are able to chose this option for free app with in-apps. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's correct but it gives a warning. One second, I will post it for you.

Comment: @Elletlar I got it, you are talking about "Pricing & distribution" tab, but I'm talking about separate list of countries for alpha build. The behavior of this list kinda buggy.

Comment: Ah okay...But it still isn't right because if you look at my image it clearly shows that the "Rest of the World" is available to alpha, beta and production.

Answer (score 0):

Warning dialog shown when selecting rest of the world for app with in-app purchases:

[image]

What screen looks like after selecting rest of world in distribution:

[image]